# Put Windows "Interactive Live SDK" in Ruby-on-Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, onedrive

I am trying to make a Rails App that can upload a file to Microsoft Skydrive/Onedrive and then save the resulting embed code in my database.  It looks like I want to use [Interactive Live SDK](http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/Default.aspx) because the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631844.aspx) is only available to apps with services using Microsoft account.

My problem is that when I go to the [SDK download page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/dn630256) it's available for Windows, iOS, and Android, but I develop on Ubuntu and my web app is going to be put on an Ubuntu server.  I also did a rudimentary search for an equivalent Ruby Gem but I wasn't able to find anything.

Is there a way around using the SDK?  Or a way to get it to work on Ubuntu?  The scope of my app isn't large, and I only need to create 1 Microsoft Live account with a public folder which I will always use.  I feel like it should be possible to put my login credentials directly in the REST calls instead of worrying about authenticity tokens, but I can't find any documentation for that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use a single OneDrive account for data across all clients of your app. The OneDrive APIs are designed around each user authenticating through the app and then accessing their own OneDrive to read/store files. Because OneDrive uses OAuth 2 and only supports grant flows that require web UI, there is no way to store credentials and pass them directly into the authentication layer. OneDrive requires the user to sign in at least once to generate the authentication tokens.

You can [request that your app has offline access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx) to the account, through the **wl.offline_access** scope. If you do that, your app receives a refresh token that can be used to generate access tokens in the future without requiring the user to login again. This gives you more flexibility, but even the refresh tokens expire after not being used for a significant period of time.

If you just need a single cloud location, that isn't differentiated per user, to store data that is shared among all app users, check out the [Azure Storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179355.aspx). There you just have an app key that gets you into the storage location and user login wouldn't be required. Of course, data stored that isn't available through OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

The Interactive Live SDK is sample code for the demonstrating how to use the Live Connect API's.  The API's use OAuth for authentication.  You will need to get an applicationID to create a login request. The authenticated user will also have to grant permissions to the application making the requests via login scopes.  You can then craft your request and include the access_token to retrieve the information you are after.

I believe there are libraries that can help you manage the OAuth authentication for ruby on rails such as OAuth Gem.

Comment: Using REST here is how to sign in a user.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx